# iTunes won't show my Cloud music?

Tags: itunes, icloud, preferences

My iTunes keeps crashing whenever I try to show my Cloud Music. I go into Preferences > Store and check the box to show the music, but then it tries to load it and it crashes. It'll keep crashing each time I load iTunes unless i check the box off, but I want my Cloud Music seen. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: If you use your Console app in your utility folder, paste here what is happening at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

click "view"-> "show icloud music purchase"

note: you have to show menu bar first to see "view" menus

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Apple then Software Update and you see an update there for iTunes, do the update.

I believe this issue was suppose to be resolved in that update.

If not, you could try signing out of the iTunes Store and signing back in. Sometimes refreshing the account information manually will help.

Lastly, you can reinstall Mac OS X from the recovery partition. Hold down opt key on boot, choose Recovery 10.X.X. On the resulting window, choose reinstall Mac OS X and then choose your hard drive.

**Create a backup before performing last step**